# How to sort words in alphabetical order from a sentence, not array

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, alphabetical

I'm trying to take sentences from a user and storing them to compare them later, but i want them to be alphabetial, like;

```
Apple
Banana
```

taken from a string like, "Banana, Oranges And Apples"; So before that i first cut the words i don't want but i don't know how I'll go about sorting since PHP sort() seems to only work on array

```
  <?php 
$str = 'Man Methord Wifi HOlla Teddy Husband';
$result = trim( preg_replace(
    "/[^a-z0-9']+([a-z0-9']{1,5}[^a-z0-9']+)*/i",
    " ",
    " $str "
) );
$lower_str = strtolower ($result);
echo $lower_str;
?>
```

Comment: `Explode` the sentence into an array. `Sort` it. `Implode` back into a sentence.

Comment: $array = explode(" ",strtolower($str)); sort($array);

Answer (score 1):

This function may work for you :

```
function sortstring($string,$unique = false) {
  $string = str_replace('.', '', $string);
  $array = explode(' ',strtolower($string)); 
  if ($unique) $array = array_unique($array);
  sort($array);
  return implode(' ',$array);  
}
```

You can find this function and its example usage at http://www.wordinn.com/solution/226/php-sort-words-sentences

Answer (score 0):

It has got an easy function that is called `sort()`.In sort function, there are many type of different sort algorithms working on sort function.This function has got 2 parameters.First parameter of sort function is array which will be sort and Second one is about type of sort algorithm.

```
<?php 
$data = array("a","k","b","z","i","v");
sort($data,SORT_STRING);
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: and where do you convert the string to array?